# Selecting fields that are not in GROUP BY when nested SELECTS aren't allowed

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, having

I have the tables:

```sql
Product(code (PK), pname, (....), sid (FK)),
Supplier(sid(PK), sname, (....))
```

The assignment is:

> Find Suppliers that supply only one product. Display their name (`sname`) and product name (`pname`).

It seem to me like a `GROUP BY` problem, so I used:

```sql
SELECT sid FROM
Product GROUP BY sid
HAVING CAST(COUNT(*) AS INTEGER) = 1;
```

This query have found me the list of `sid`'s that supply one product only, but now I have encountered a problem:

- The assignment forbids any form of nested `SELECT` queries.
- The result of the query I have written has only one column. (The `sid` column)
- Thus, I am unable to access the product name as it is not in the query result table, and if I would have added it to the `GROUP BY` statement, then the grouping will based on product name as well, which is an unwanted behavior.

How should I approach the problem, then?

*Note: I use PostgreSQL*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can phrase the query as:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.sname, MAX(p.pname) as pname
FROM Product p JOIN
     Supplier s
     ON p.sid = s.sid
GROUP BY s.sid, s.sname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

You don't need to convert `COUNT(*)` to an integer.  It is already an integer.

Comment: Grate solution! but what about sname? (it is in the other table) It need to be selected too.

Answer (score 1):

You could put

```
max(pname)
```

in the `SELECT` list. That's an aggregate, so it would be fine.

Comment: Buy how do I include sname as well?

Comment: In the same way, using `max`.